# How to get dynamically changed Key's value in JSON String using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse my JSON code through jQuery but I stuck with this situation.

My JSON code :

```
var options = 
    "Group": { /* This will dynamically change depending on user input */
        "Setting 1" : { /* This will dynamically change too depending on user input */
            "id": "related_posts",
            "name": "Related Posts",
            "desc": "Show Related Posts",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "std": 0
        },
        "Setting 2": { /* Also this will dynamically change depending on user input */
            "id": "breaking_news",
            "name": "Breaking News",
            "desc": "Hide Breaking News",
            "type": "checkbox",
            "std": 1
        }
    }
```

I tried this but it work only if it's constant :

```
options.Group["Setting 1"].id
```

In conclusion I want a method to get dynamic keys.

I forget to mention that I'm still learning jQuery so I don't have a lot of knowledge about it.

Comment: so `options[groupName][settingName].id` ?

Comment: @Pointy but how can I get the groupName and settingsName with jQuery because this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: jQuery isn't going to help you at all. You can use `for ... in` to iterate through the property names of an object, or the `Object.keys()` function.

Comment: @Pointy If you don't mind could you write the code for me because I'm still a beginner. Thanks

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for your help, I found the solution.